# PHP concatenate variable in url using curl function

Tags: php

```
<?php   
 $msg1="Good Morning";

$url = 'http://smslane.com/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?
user=ABC&password=1234&msisdn=91**********&sid=WEBSMS&msg='.$msg1.'&fl=0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

I have to send sms through my code. I have an SMS API. I am trying to send $msg1 by concatenating the variable to the url. Please help.

Comment: so you can really login over `http` (not `https`) with login data as GET parameter?

Comment: First try removing the new line in the middle of your URL

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `urlencode` the message as it is going to be a part of a URL.

```
// $msg = "Good Morning";
$msg = urlencode($msg);
// $msg = "Good%20Morning"
```